# How can I change delete button style?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

How can I change delete button style in xcode4.2 for ios 5.0?

Comment: EditTable delete button Style I think !!

Answer (score 0):

You can always make your own button with images. Select Type `Custom` and select image for your button. Don't forget to select Highlighted image for best user experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to tableView delete button, here's the trick,

The following delegate will be called first when you do swipe action,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    indexForEdit=indexPath.row; //Store the row index
    edit=1;
    [tableView reloadData];  
}
```

Then in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** code as follows,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Create a custom cell
if((indexPath.row==indexForEdit)&&(edit==1))
    {
        edit=0;
        UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //Set frame 
        [customButton setTitle:@"Delete" forState:normal];
        [customButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];  
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customButton];
    }
}
```